# objc[89368]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both

Tags: swift, xcode

Im working on a `MapKit` project  with the latest versions of Swift(4.2) and Xcode(9.4.1). I'm working with Pods( `alamofire`, `alamofireImage`) right now and can’t seem to get past this error:

> objc[89368]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace
>   (0x12250f4d0) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference
>   (0x12163be38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I've cleaned the project/build several times and reset the simulator, but have had no luck so far. Additionally, I’ve tried looking throughout the apple forum and stack overflow but I haven’t had any luck so far. If anyone has suggestions on what to do it would be much appreciated!

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Erase simulator content and settings: in simulator, do **Hardware->Erase All Content and Settings**
- Clean the project (**Command + Shift + K**)
- Clean the build folder (**Command + Option + Shift + K**)

Try to run again your project.

Comment: Tried this multiple times, doesn't help at all. Anything else I can try?